# Not receiving iMessages when on 3G

Tags: messages, cellular-data

I have only had this phone (iPhone 5s) a few days and transferred my number.  The problem is when my phone is on 3G it's no receiving iMessage, I have missed important messages.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you able to access the internet in general, or is it only iMessages giving you trouble?

Comment: Do they come in later? iMessage defaults to SMS when sent from another iPhone. It seems that it would have done that from the sender's phone. I recommend turning iMessage off then back on. Sometimes that helps.